# Nullpointerexception when checking EditText value

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I get a nullpointerexception when I do this:

```
EditText[] answers;
```

//At the oncreate method I do this:this is set after the setContent() method.

```
   answers=new EditText[6];
     answers[0]=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     answers[1]=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     answers[2]=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     answers[3]=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
     answers[4]=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
     answers[5]=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
```

In the onClickListener of the button I put this:

```
nextQuestion_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    for(EditText item : answers) { 
        if(item.getText().toString().equals("")) { //nuller Exception here
            editTextIsEmpty=true;
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

why do I get a nullpointerexception... in the if statement?

UPDATE; 
I put all the EditText into an array. All the code is inside the onCreate method

This is what I get:

```
 11-29 16:11:24.076: E/AndroidRuntime(616): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 16:11:24.076: E/AndroidRuntime(616): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 16:11:24.076: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at com.NewOrder.SetTest$1.onClick(SetTest.java:95)
11-29 16:11:24.076: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-29 16:11:24.076: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-29 16:11:24.076: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-29 16:11:24.076: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-29 16:11:24.076: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
```

Comment: Could this be because `answers[]` is still null? you never actually assigned anything to it.  You only assigned values to the answer# variables.

Comment: sorry, I didnt include that in my answer..updated answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
answers = new EditText[7];
answer1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
answer2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
answer3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
answer4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
answer5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
answer6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
```

Should be:

```
answers = new EditText[6];
answers[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
answers[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
answers[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
answers[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
answers[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
answers[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
```

Otherwise you aren't ever adding anything to the `answers` array, as has been stated. It seems to me that you're thinking `answer1` through `answer6` are going into your `answers` array, unless you have those declared elsewhere that you haven't posted. All 6 `EditTexts` in your `answers` array are currently `null`, which is causing your Exception.

Also, something like this would be more concise:

```
int[] editTexts = { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText2, R.id.editText3, 
    R.id.editText4, R.id.editText5, R.id.editText6 };

EditText[] answers = new EditText[editTexts.length];

for(int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    answers[i] = (EditText)findViewById(editTexts[i]);
}
```

Comment: upvote for a bit more concise answer than mine, though realistically OP doesn't even need to stick them in their own array for what he is doing.  The findViewById() can be put into the last loop.

Comment: check the answer I updated above... Your post is a bit older.. .. even when I call at the end to answers[0].. and do something like this.. answer[0].getText().toString, and try to include it as a message in a log... it throws that exception.. the answers[0] seems to be null

Comment: noo..I get it now.. I mistyped the first R.id.editText1... thats why it didnt find the id.. I thought eclipse shows a compile error whenever I refer to that in the resource... I will accept your answer anyway

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: True! It could certainly be done more efficiently that way. :) Upvoted you as well.

Answer (score 2):

You might try asking a question explicitly, it will engender more helpful answers. :)

Two things.  You need to make sure you are doing your `answer1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);` calls before your `item.getText().toString().equals("")` calls, or you will always get a nullref error.

The other problem is that you are never actually assigning anything to the `answers` array.  You need to put each of these `EditText`s into the array before you can use it, or it will always be empty.

Try this:

```
answers = new EditText[6]();
answers[0] = answer0;
answers[1] = answer1;
...
answers[5] = answer5;
```

The code should work when you do that.

EDIT to reflect changes in question:

Put your assignment code (`answers[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);`) inside `onResume()`, not in `onCreate()`.  The `EditText`s have not been given `id`s at the point, and will give nullrefs.

Comment: wasnt that what I did above..did you just skim

Comment: ..lol..funny syntax answers = new EditText[6](); is that C++?

Comment: You need to put all of this code in your `onResume()` method, NOT `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure those `EditText` ids are from the current activity's layout, and `findViewById()` method calls are after `setContentView()` method call.

Comment: That was my first thought,,but the mistake was in the xml file.. I got no compile error..so I couldnt have guessed

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the onclick method of the onclicklistener in the code you provided

Comment: it is all inside the onclick method..Otherwise there will be a compile error

Comment: I know, but it is missing from the code you provided in your question. Editing your code before posting it here will only hide the original error, the error you want fixed, which is what happened here.